# Utilización del paquete psycopg2

Tags: python

Necesito realizar un programa donde se deberá guardar el archivo Base_autos.csv en una base de datos creada en PosgreSQL.

Indicaciones:

- nombre de la base de datos: concesionario
- nombre de la tabla: autos
- Deberán crear un módulo (nombre del modulo conexion_postgres.py) que
  se encargue de:
  Conexión con la base
  Ingresar los datos leídos del archivo Base_autos.csv
  Editar registros (enviando como parámetro id)
  Eliminar registros (enviando como parámetro el id del registro
- Se deberán controlar los errores.

y dentro del archivo Base_autos.csv esta los siguientes elementos

```
Empresa;Año;Monto Ventas;Mercado;Cantidad
Chevrolet;2010;105;20;95
Targit;2010;68;114;46
Ufan;2010;101;156;55
Volkswagen;2010;12;25;13
Renault;2010;11;253;143
Chevrolet;2010;100;20;3
Hynduai;2010;12;217;97
Porsche;2010;100;20;3
Skoda;2010;100;20;3
Hino;2010;65;116;51
Mazda;2010;149;274;125
Citroen;2010;112;24;128
Kia;2010;148;26;112
Mitsubishi;2010;100;20;3
Honda;2010;100;20;3
UB Trucks;2010;103;214;111
Toyota;2010;128;287;159
Mercedes;2010;81;136;55
Chery;2010;73;125;52
Nissan;2010;100;20;3
Jmc;2010;5;9;4
Chevrolet;2011;111;208;97
Targit;2011;89;148;59
Ufan;2011;112;182;7
Volkswagen;2011;121;232;111
Renault;2011;105;249;144
Chevrolet;2011;78;126;48
Hynduai;2011;117;232;115
Porsche;2011;100;20;3
Skoda;2011;100;20;3
Hino;2011;45;86;41
Mazda;2011;142;27;128
Citroen;2011;135;264;129
Kia;2011;151;28;129
Mitsubishi;2011;98;155;57
Honda;2011;54;108;54
UB Trucks;2011;127;229;102
Toyota;2011;129;289;16
DongFeng;2011;65;111;46
Mercedes;2011;92;179;87
BMW;2011;73;119;46
Chery;2011;7;119;49
Nissan;2011;100;20;3
Jmc;2011;59;10;41
Chevrolet;2012;138;234;96
Targit;2012;4;91;51
Ufan;2012;145;226;81
Volkswagen;2012;115;225;11
Renault;2012;104;246;142
Chevrolet;2012;66;107;41
Hynduai;2012;13;238;108
Porsche;2012;71;91;2
Skoda;2012;26;82;56
Hino;2012;76;136;6
Mazda;2012;149;27;121
Citroen;2012;146;271;125
Kia;2012;134;262;128
Mitsubishi;2012;95;156;61
Honda;2012;2;85;65
UB Trucks;2012;132;234;102
Toyota;2012;125;295;17
Mercedes;2012;61;136;75
Chery;2012;49;105;56
Nissan;2012;35;84;49
Jmc;2012;8;127;47
Chevrolet;2013;100;20;3
Chevrolet;2013;133;247;114
Targit;2013;47;89;42
Ufan;2013;153;256;103
Volkswagen;2013;141;274;133
Renault;2013;102;257;155
Chevrolet;2013;74;131;57
Hynduai;2013;151;266;115
Porsche;2013;100;20;3
Porsche;2013;96;146;5
Skoda;2013;61;115;54
Hino;2013;79;168;89
Mazda;2013;147;271;124
Citroen;2013;135;257;122
Kia;2013;16;293;133
Mitsubishi;2013;119;187;68
Honda;2013;66;115;49
UB Trucks;2013;132;234;102
Great Wall;2013;100;20;3
Toyota;2013;145;315;17
Ford;2013;45;107;62
DongFeng;2013;100;20;3
Mercedes;2013;8;135;55
BMW;2013;91;136;45
Lifan;2013;115;191;76
Chery;2013;4;88;48
Nissan;2013;7;166;96
Jmc;2013;82;161;79
Chevrolet;2014;82;133;51
Chevrolet;2014;116;238;122
Targit;2014;59;109;5
Ufan;2014;153;276;123
Volkswagen;2014;119;257;138
Renault;2014;118;241;123
Chevrolet;2014;78;124;46
Hynduai;2014;14;263;123
Porsche;2014;42;6;18
Porsche;2014;98;178;8
Skoda;2014;92;188;96
Hino;2014;87;19;103
Mazda;2014;109;23;121
Citroen;2014;106;223;117
Kia;2014;136;261;125
Mitsubishi;2014;11;161;51
Honda;2014;96;174;78
UB Trucks;2014;107;21;103
Great Wall;2014;32;67;35
Toyota;2014;119;259;14
Ford;2014;98;183;85
DongFeng;2014;100;20;3
Mercedes;2014;88;151;63
BMW;2014;91;147;56
Lifan;2014;12;218;98
Chery;2014;5;99;49
Nissan;2014;98;216;118
Jmc;2014;69;118;49
Chevrolet;2015;77;145;68
Chevrolet;2015;95;205;11
Targit;2015;8;143;63
Ufan;2015;146;257;111
Volkswagen;2015;108;253;145
Renault;2015;104;246;142
Chevrolet;2015;58;118;6
Hynduai;2015;121;228;107
Porsche;2015;87;15;63
Porsche;2015;92;182;9
Skoda;2015;78;176;98
Hino;2015;78;182;104
Mazda;2015;102;214;112
Citroen;2015;105;217;112
Kia;2015;112;219;107
Mitsubishi;2015;108;205;97
Honda;2015;100;20;3
UB Trucks;2015;104;21;106
Great Wall;2015;100;20;3
Toyota;2015;105;244;139
Ford;2015;91;171;8
Jacr;2015;74;165;91
DongFeng;2015;100;20;3
Mercedes;2015;74;127;53
BMW;2015;100;20;3
Lifan;2015;117;213;96
Chery;2015;100;20;3
Nissan;2015;86;193;107
Jmc;2015;44;112;68
Chevrolet;2016;32;94;62
Chevrolet;2016;43;147;104
Targit;2016;100;20;3
Ufan;2016;118;247;129
Chevrolet;2016;5;123;73
Volkswagen;2016;95;219;124
Renault;2016;86;211;125
Chevrolet;2016;100;20;3
Volvo;2016;55;119;64
Hynduai;2016;112;25;138
Porsche;2016;47;102;55
Porsche;2016;100;20;3
Porsche;2016;22;108;86
Skoda;2016;5;156;106
Hino;2016;100;20;3
Mazda;2016;100;20;3
Citroen;2016;77;194;117
Kia;2016;109;271;162
Mitsubishi;2016;54;1104;105
Honda;2016;100;20;3
UB Trucks;2016;5;125;75
Great Wall;2016;100;20;3
Toyota;2016;57;193;136
Ford;2016;72;149;77
QRC;2016;75;153;78
Jacr;2016;12;92;8
DongFeng;2016;100;20;3
Zotye;2016;52;153;101
Mercedes;2016;53;131;78
BMW;2016;100;20;3
Lifan;2016;95;188;93
Jac;2016;31;15;119
Chery;2016;100;20;3
Nissan;2016;97;226;129
Jmc;2016;100;20;3
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema que tienes para hacer eso?

Comment: honestamente no tengo idea de como hacerlo, perdi el hilo de clase ese dia y el profesor no me quiere ayudar con eso

Comment: Me temo que en StackOverflow no podemos ayudarte a menos que hayas intentado algo. Ya que si intentaramos ayudarte, terminaríamos haciendote la tarea, lo que perjudicaría tu aprendizaje. Lamento que no seamos de ayuda. Espero que la respuesta que alguien llegó a dejar antes de que la pregunta sea cerrada te sirva para sustituir la parte de la clase perdida y que hayas aprendido algo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es instalar el paquete de `psycopg2`:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

En un archivo de Python importamos la paquetería y conectamos con Postgre (para esto ya debiste haber creado un usuario y una BD, te dejo un [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-y-utilizar-postgresql-en-ubuntu-16-04-es) de configuración de Postgre si usas Ubuntu, que sería lo ideal):

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres")
```

Debes crear una tabla con el nombre `Autos` con los campos: `Empresa;Año;Monto Ventas;Mercado;Cantidad` como lo mencionas.

Por último poblamos la BD con tu archivo `.csv`, por lo que tu archivo de Pyhton debe quedar algo así:

```
import csv
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open('Base_autos.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # Ignora la primer fila que tiene el nombre de los campos.
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO Autos VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        row
    )
conn.commit()
```

Comment: y si digamos que la base de datos tiene alguna clave?

Comment: Solamente la agregas a los parámetros de conexión: `conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=password123")`

Comment: me sale este error 'psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"'

Comment: Ese error sale porque estas introduciendo las credenciales incorrectas, verifica que el nombre de usuario y contraseña coincidan con las que pusiste cuando configuraste Postgre.

Comment: ya ahora si cree la conexion pero me sale ahora este error: cur.execute(
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: No te puedo seguir ayudando si no haces el intento por hacerlo tu, te ayudé con un gran avance con la respuesta.